# Safely dynamically change SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli

I have the following method in my class. My goal is basically to find all managers in the database but with the option to limit the sql statement. For example `" AND U.username='jake56'` or `" AND A.firstName='Jake'`. I am wondering if this is safe to have the option to add the limits for it is susceptible to SQL injection.

```
/**
  * Returns an array of manager Users
  * @param string (optional) $limits - limit the query EX: 'AND U.userId > 7'
  * @return an array of managers with associative arrays
  */
  public function find_all_managers($limits = '') {
    $sql = "SELECT U.*, A.* 
     FROM Users U 
    JOIN Address A 
    ON U.addressId=A.addressId 
    WHERE U.role='manager' " . $limits;
    // run the query 
    $result = $this->query($query);
    $managers = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    return $managers;
  }
```

Is this safe to have that parameter? I was told this method is susceptible for SQL injection but I don't see another way around limiting the query if I want. 
For example I might want to `$db->find_all_managers(' WHERE A.lastName='smith')`

Comment: You should use parameterized queries though, anything that can be manually input to the query can potentially exploit it. Then there's the question of, what if you input an invalid condition? I would rather build the query dynamically based on the input, not have the input the direct part of the query .

Answer (score -2):

Do this

```
public function find_all_managers($limitA = 0,$limitB = 0) {
     //now create the limit part here, if real numbers given
     //if(is_numeric($limitA) and $limitA > 0)  
}
```

So know you create the limit and nothing else can be injected.

Comment: You misunderstood the question. Although the word "limiting" is misleading, the example is rather certain. It's always worth to read the question to the last line

Comment: @Your Common Sense 2 `where`s in one SQL will never work, please dont blame me on that. I have answer about 90% of the question right. After reading the last line again, i thing question can be closed, to wide, to unclear. And someone, who can, can delete my answer :-) And i will take more time in the future and will wait till the question is set up right. instance fail can happen